# Converting String value represent as currency to normal Float or Integer

Tags: java, netbeans, currency

While working on currency I need to change a value of a JTextBox(say txtRetilPrice) in the format of Rs.1,500.00. Now for manipulation, I need to change the value of txtRetailPrice to 1500. I tried this code but couldn't succeed.

```
if (!(txtRetailPrice.getText().equals(""))) {
            txtRetailPrice.setText(txtRetailPrice.getText().replaceAll("Rs", ""));
            txtRetailPrice.setText(txtRetailPrice.getText().replaceAll(".", ""));
            txtRetailPrice.setText(txtRetailPrice.getText().replaceAll(",", ""));

}
```

Actually, on the got focus of the JTextBox, I want to show as 1500 and on the lost focus, it will change to Rs.1,500.00. The lost focus' work is done but for this I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NumberFormat` class to get this done using `India` as the country and `English` as the language for `Locale`. Here is a simple example for both parsing and formatting.

```
static void IndiaCurrencyFormat() throws ParseException {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
        int number = 15000;
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
        String currency = "Rs.15,000.00";
        System.out.println(numberFormat.parse(currency));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, @GSSwain I had gone through and receive what I want. Thanks :)